# use of: while (cin >> x) and eof

Tags: c++

I am not so sure how the  works I suppose is my root problem here. I've read a few previous posts on while(cin>>x) but nothing seems to answer my question really.
I am using this loop to read in some text data:

```
while (cin >> x){
    searchText.push_back(x);
}
```

but then later in the code I am trying to read in a single word using:

```
cout << "Please enter your target word: ";
string targetWord;
cin >> targetWord;
```

but the above while loop/ eof seems to scupper the 2nd code snippet (if I move the 2nd code snippet up above it all works fine, but obviously that is not what im trying to do)

*EDIT*
Here is the full code for clarity:

```
int main()
{
// ask for the target word
//   cout << "Please enter your target word: ";
//   string targetWord;
//   cin >> targetWord;

   // ask for and read the search text
   cout <<  "Enter the complete search text, "
            "followed by end-of-file: ";
   vector<string> searchText;
   string x;
   while (cin >> x){
      searchText.push_back(x);
   }

   // check that some text was entered
   typedef vector<string>::size_type vec_sz;
   vec_sz size = searchText.size();
   if (size == 0){
      cout << endl <<   "You must enter some text. "
                        "Please try again." << endl;
      return 1;
   }

// ask for the target word
   cin.clear();
   cout << "";
   cout << "Please enter your target word: ";
   string targetWord;
   cin >> targetWord;


   int count = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<size; ++i){
      if (targetWord == searchText[i]){
      count++;
      }
   }

   cout  << "The target word [" << targetWord << "] was "
            "in the search text " << count << " times." << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I am just trying to take in some text from the user... then a search word and see how many times the word appears in the entered text (pretty simple!)

I know I could do it differently but the question here is more about how can I use the cout/ cin stream again after it has had an EOF in it previously

Comment: What do you mean by "scupper"?

Comment: I think that the first snippet with the loop stops the second one from working, when the second is placed after the first.
Maybe there's something in the stdin buffer? tried cin.clear() or something along those lines?

Comment: Similar question (and possible solution) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095291/reusing-stdcin-after-eof

Comment: How do you come out of the first loop. Did you enter `ctrl-D` to get out of the loop. If not, you will never get out of the loop and will never execute the second snippet.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam You get out of the loop as soon as you fail to read into whatever the type of `x` is.

Comment: @dutt: "stops the second one from working" is no clearer than "scupper". I was asking for symptoms.

Comment: @BoBTFish I know that but I am asking that if he does that. If not I suggested a way for that. It is not very much clear what is happening(it is only suggested that "while loop/ eof seems to scupper the 2nd code snippet"), but at the same time it is suggested that reversing the thing works.

Comment: @MarceloCantos Scupper - to defeat, ruin, destroy, put an end to.

Comment: I think Marcelo was not querying the word as such, but looking for a more distinct description of "what goes wrong".

Comment: The names of the variables (`searchText`, `targetWord`) suggest that `x` is a string.  If so, the only reason the first loop will terminate is because there is no more data to be read.  And if there is no more data to be read, then there is no more data to be read.  End of file is (or should be) sticky at the `filebuf` level as well, and there's no way to reset that.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos... yes you are right to ask, it was silly to use a local/ slang term! I meant the first code snippet stops the 2nd snippet from behaving as it would if it stood alone

Comment: @Aman Deep Gautam yes I am using ctrl-D to end my first input

Comment: @mbbxedh2: Using slang is fine. I knew full well what "scupper" means, and even if I didn't, the definition is a right-click away in my browser. The problem was — and still is! — that you didn't state what actually went wrong. Did the second block of code crash? not run? produce unexpected output? something else? It's a moot point now, since you've clearly gotten an answer. I'm just pointing this out to help you in future. When you post a question, you should explicitly state what symptoms you are seeing and how they deviate from your expectations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `cin` (or any other `std::stream`) hits an end of file, it sets a status to indicate that this has happened.

To reset this status, you need to call `cin.clear();`, which will clear any "bad" state, and make sure the stream is "ok" to use again. This also applies if you are reading from a file, and want to restart from the beginning.

Edit: I just took the code posted above, and ran it on my machine, adding at the top

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
```

This following is the compile and run:

```
$ g++ -Wall words.cpp 
words.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
words.cpp:40:20: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
$ ./a.out
Enter the complete search text, followed by end-of-file: aa bb cc [CTRL-D]
Please enter your target word: aa
The target word [aa] was in the search text 1 times.
```

which is what I expected to see...

Edit2: For completeness: The "success rate" of using `cin.clear()` will depend on the implementation. A more reliable solution is to use a different way to mark the end of the stream of words in the first phase of the program. One could use a single `"."` or "!" or some other thing that isn't supposed to be in a "word" - or something longer, such as `"&&@&&"`, but that makes it hard to type and remember when one is 15 pages into the input.

Comment: @hagubear flushing is not resetting the state flags. Those are two different things.

Comment: Completely different from `fflush` - and certainly entirely different from `fflush(stdin)` which is UB, where `std::ios::clear()` is clearly defined http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/clear/

Comment: @MatsPetersson        Deleted my comment!

Comment: @ArneMertz    Plz ignore my comment!

Comment: I would _not_ expect this to work.  Where does the end of file condition come from.  If it is because he has read all of the data in the file, then clearing the error and expecting to continue is not going to work.  In addition, in a quality implementation, I would expect two successive calls to `filebuf::sgetc` to return the same thing.  Which means that if one returns EOF, all successive ones will, since there's no provision for extracting EOF from the sequence.  End of file is *not* a character that you can skip.

Comment: I'm expecting the data is input on keyboard and the user is pressing 'CTRL-{Z,D}' to end the input. If the input is not coming from keyboard, I agree, it won't work, and I was tempted (an hour or two ago) to edit in a comment saying "this is not a very good design, because you can't use it with `myprog < somefile`" - which may be a good edit to make). I'm not sure what else can be suggested to "fix" the problem from the OP tho'.

Comment: @MatsPetersson... I had tried cin.clear() (just before the 2nd snippet) from reading other posts around the topic but it still does not work. To be more exact once I press ctrl-d the 2nd snippet prints it's prompt to screen but the prompt does not give any time for the user to enter the search/target word (I presume because the entered eof is still dominant) and then the code completes (without the search/target word being entered though it just returns an erroneous result though)

Comment: Then I would suggest you need to post ALL of your code, and/or explain a bit further what you are doing in your code and how you complete the input.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I added an edit to the bottom of the original question with more complete details

Comment: That probably means that something is different between what I do and what you do - in environment, I expect. What OS & Compiler are you using?

Comment: An example where this kind of restarting of a closed `std::cin` does NOT work is the `libc++` library (often distributed with clang++). Although it can be made to work with an additional call to `clearerr(stdin);`

Comment: @MatsPetersson... yes it seems like an env issue. cin.clear() "does not work" on my mac but gives a result as you expected/ displayed on my ubuntu set-up

Comment: In which case I can only suggest "an alternative approach" as the solution. By which I mean "Don't end with EOF", but end with somtehing else - such as `"<<END>>"` or a single `"."` word, or some such. Which would also allow your program to accept input from the output of another program `cat sometext.txt|myprog` or something.

Comment: Whether the solution posted here works or not depends on the implementation; the standard isn't as clear as it should be here.  From a QoI point of view, however---I would expect that all successive calls to `std::filebuf::sgets()` return the same value (barring a seek or a putback of some sort).  This means that the `filebuf` will memorize the fact that it has seen end of file, and there is no way to reset this.  (I could solve his problem, but it would involve writing a new streambuf and replacing the one used by `cin`.  A rather advanced task.)

Comment: @JamesKanze The standard doesn't even suggest that `std::cin` should use `std::filebuf` (and sin some implementations it doesn't)

Comment: @Cubbi The standard does require that `std::cin` use a `streambuf`, and it implicitly requires that successive calls to `std::streambuf::sgetc()` return the same value.  (Otherwise, there's no point in the function.)  This holds for `std::filebuf` (which is the logical `streambuf` for `std::cin`), and is an implicit requirement for all other `streambuf`.  (On the other hand, all of the `istream` functions are required to set `eofbit` when they see end of file, so that they don't call `streambuf::sgetc` again.  The standard is anything but clear here.)

Answer (score 2):

When execution leaves the loop

```
while (cin >> x){
    searchText.push_back(x);
}
```

it does so because the "testing" of `cin` has returned false, in other words, `failbit` and/or `badbit` has been set on the stream. When that is the case, any further attempt to read from the stream will fail, i.e. `targetWord` will be left empty.

To make the stream usable again, you have to reset the error flags by calling `cin.clear();`

Comment: Which may or may not work, depending on how the lower levels treat the end of file.  As a general rule, I would expect it _not_ to work.

Answer (score 2):

It would be somewhat helpful if we knew the type of `x` in the
first loop, but basically: you read all of the available input,
then try to read some more, and you're surprised that it's
failing.  The contrary would surprise me.

The real question is: what are you trying to do?  Basically,
what is the type of `x`, and—I'm assuming that you're
supposing that `cin` is an interactive device because of the
prompt—how do you determine that the first input has
finished?  If the first loop ends because of "end of file" (user
entered control-D under Unix, or control-Z under Windows), then
there's no way you can reliably expect to read more.  Resetting
the error status with `cin.clear()` *might* work; it will cause
the `istream` to try to read more from the `streambuf`.  But it
might not; there are any number of layers below the `istream`
which, for whatever reason, may have memorized the end of file.
So you'll have to find some different way of recognizing the
end.

Just guessing from the names of the variables: if you're trying
to read a list of words, I'd use `std::getline`, with an empty
line for the end of the list.  So the first loop would become:

```
while ( std::getline( std::cin, x ) && x != "" ) {
    searchText.push_back( x );
}
if ( ! std::cin ) {
    //  Something really bad has happened...
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to break up the line on white
space, to allow more than one word per line (and to ignore any
extra white space in the line:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( std::cin, x ) && x != "" ) {
    std::istringstream l( line );
    while ( l >> x ) {
        searchText.push_back( x );
    }
}
if ( ! std::cin ) //  ...
```

Even if `x` has some other type, you might want to consider
something along these lines.

Comment: @JamesKanze... I just added an edit to my original question to give some more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I used cin.clear() and on my mac set-up it did not seem to clear the EOF but on a ubuntu set-up it did clear the stream

Apple:

```
(Canopy 32bit) joes-imac:chap3 joe$ g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

Ubuntu:

```
joe@joe-HPlaptop:~$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I am happy to accept it is just compiler differences and finish/ close the issue (was a silly little one really!)

Thanks for all the help though (my first stackoverflow question actually!)

Comment: Did you try `cin.clear(); clearerr(stdin);` on your mac setup?

Answer (score 0):

cin will stop when it will encounter endline character or a newline. So every time you enter something and hit enter it you are providing an '\n'. while(cin>>x){} should be used to read input continuously without endline/'\n'.