# c++ How split one line into two from a text file then store each into two different arrays?

Tags: c++, vector

Say, I have this on a text file

```
1   15
2   20
3   25
4   30
5   35
```

how do I split them so that I store the first column on vector x, and the second column in vector y?

Comment: `std::getline(istream& is, string& str, char delim)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is clean and that you know how to open a file:

```
while(std::cin >> x >> y){
    vectorx.pushback(x);
    vectory.pushback(y);
}
```

`std::cin` doesn't read whitespaces.  You can use `std::cin` to read data from a file as long as your data is predictably organized and you know the datatypes.  Otherwise, you may have to look into using `std::getline()`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with the simplest solution and then gradually refine it to using stream iterators and the like. Then you'll get an impression of the power of the C++ (template) libraries.

Pseudo-code:

```
Open file
Declare vectors x and y
while ( not end-of-file )
{
    int tmp1, tmp2;
    stream into tmp1 and tmp2
    check stream status for format violations
    add tmp1 to x, add tmp2 to y
}
```

Comment: Since you went all "stream iterators" and such, knowing OP has no clue what you're talking about.  Your while loop shouldn't search for eof. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404192/use-of-while-cin-x-and-eof

Comment: There are multiple ways to get this done but please enlighten me as to why checking for eof is so bad here.